# Vibration of particles in EM waves

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

We can  find the direction of vibration of a  particle by shifting the wave in the dirction of wave travels. Is this applicable for EM waves as well?

Answer (score 0):

A small charged particle will tend to oscillate with the electric field as an EM wave moves by.  However, as the particle moves, it is also subject to a magnetic force (in the direction that the wave is moving).  This explains how the wave can exert pressure on a surface.